# Parsing pcap using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, wireshark, tshark

I am trying to parse pcap file using bash script

The command is stored in the form of bash array

```
cmd=( tshark -nr $pcap -z conv,tcp, "(ip.src == $client1 && ip.dst == $server ) || (ip.dst == $client1 && ip.src == $server)" -q  )
```

And then is executed as follows

```
"${cmd[@]}" > statistics.csv
```

But the problem is that the filter specified after `"conv,tcp"` in the above array is not being applied.

Please help with this.

Thanks

Comment: Is there an extra comma up there? `conv,tcp,`

Comment: Yes its there. Even then its not working

Comment: is there more to this than you're showing? executing $cmd stuffed with shell quoting and sub-shell characters seems overly baroque, and an invitation to trouble. Why not just `tshark -nr $pcap .... > stats.csv` ? Good luck.

Comment: You have a space character between "`conv,tcp,`" and the quoted filter. That will make it a separate argument to tshark, instead of the single argument after `-z`, which probably won't work.